# Incorporating defaults and user inputs in list of initial conditions in Python

Tags: python, lazy-initialization

I'm working on a library of thermodynamic functions. Many of these functions involve finding roots, which requires initial guesses for the values. I want to provide a suggested function for getting these initial guesses, but still allow users to provide other initial guesses. The solution I came up with ends up looking like (for example):

```
def eq_tp(temp,pres,initairf=None,initdhum=None):
    if any(init is None for init in (initairf,initdhum)):
        res = approx_tp(temp,pres)
        if initairf is None: initairf = res[0]
        if initdhum is None: initdhum = res[1]
    x0 = [initairf,initdhum]
    ...
```

where `approx_tp` is the default function for getting initial conditions.

Is there a more "pythonic" way of doing this, or any downsides to this approach? Typically, the approximation functions are pretty fast, so I could do that calculation every time and skip the `if any` construct, but it seems better to avoid that calculation if it's unnecessary. In this example, there are only 2 initial values to fill in, but that number ranges from 1-6, so filling in the `x0` array could be done better. Since this is a construct repeated a few *dozen* times in the library, I do want it to be fairly fast but readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good. This is an alternative that calls `approx_tp` every time:

```
def eq_tp(temp, pres, initairf=None, initdhum=None):
    x0 = [default if value is None else value for default, value
          in zip(approx_tp(temp, pres), [initairf, initdhum])]
```

If you want to call the function only if necessary, you can use this version:

```
def eq_tp(temp, pres, initairf=None, initdhum=None):
    default_args = default_values = (initairf, initdhum)
    if any(init is None for init in default_args):
        default_values = approx_tp(temp, pres)
    x0 = [default if value is None else value for default, value
          in zip(default_values, default_args)]
```

This would also work for three or more default arguments without adding more lines, just add them to `default_args`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I like how compact the first one is. I tend to forget that conditionals can be used that way inside generators. In the second, are there any potential issues with the double-definition `x = y = ...`? I guess everything gets set to the right-most quantity, so overwriting `default_values` isn't an issue, but I'm not very familiar with how secure that is.

Comment: The `default_args = default_values = (initairf, initdhum)` poses no problem. Both `default_args` and  `default_values` should be the same. If one of them is  `None`, the name `default_values`  will be re-used for new values and there is no reference to `default_args`  anymore.